# Does Leech Field allow you to absorb your own powers, your Schism's powers, or your Fission's powers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

> You raise a field of potentiality that drains the vitality from
> powers that you successfully save against. When you succeed on a
> saving throw to negate the effect of a **foe’s power** on you, and the
> power is one that leech field is effective against (see below), your
> body erupts in a brief flash of crackling dark energy. You gain 1
> power point for every 2 power points **your foe** spent to manifest the
> power you just saved against (to a maximum number of points equal to
> your manifester level). You cannot gain power points that would cause
> you to exceed your normal daily maximum.
>
> This power is effective against any power that targets a single
> creature and allows the target a saving throw to negate it, except
> those that are delivered by a touch attack or a ranged touch attack
> (including a ray).

You, your Schism, and your Fission are not "foes". Or can they be? Allies you target you with harmful powers can be considered "foes" right? Like in a sparring match?

Or instead, does this power work on all powers regardless if it's a "foe" or not because the first sentence says you drain vitality from any and all powers you successfully save against, regardless of whether it's from a "foe" or not, and the last sentence says it's effective against any power that targets a single creature and allows a saving throw to negate? As in "foe's power" is just an example rather than an all encompassing requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ask your DM, it might work

The rules have nothing conclusive to tell us on this. Foe is not a defined term in 3.5e. Using the normal [English definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foe), foe means things such as:

> - one who has personal enmity for another
> - an enemy in war

Using these defintions, your schism as a "second mind" of yourself, or your fission as a "duplicate of yourself", both allied with you one presumes, appear to be a bad fit here, as they are neither of these things.

The rules however use foe in a few instances in the [magic armor and weapon rules](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#table-bane-weapon-designated-foe), there often as a stand-in of "the creature you are attacking", otherwise the use would mean that you could, for example, damage friends with a *life-drinker* weapon without imposing negative levels. If your DM aims to be consistent with that, they could rule that anyone you attack with a feature can be considered your foe.

As an other example, for the *invisibility* spell, foe is specifically described like this:

> For purposes of this spell, an attack includes any spell targeting a foe or whose area or effect includes a foe. (Exactly who is a foe **depends on the invisible character’s perceptions**.)

Here, who is a foe or not depends on the character's perception. There is just no consistent use of the word across the rules.

So, this really comes down to if your DM thinks this use is a legalese exploit of the wording opposed to the intent and will disallow it, or not. If they are fine with it, it could work.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149525/discussion-on-answer-by-nobody-the-hobgoblin-does-leech-field-allow-you-to-absor); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.